# when using laravel chatify package the image is not being shown

Tags: laravel

here is code in filesystem.php:

```
 'public' => [

        'driver' => 'local',

        'root' => public_path('/images'),

        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',

        'visibility' => 'public',

        'throw' => false,
    ],
```

the image is being saved in public/images/attachments folder but it wont display. when try to open it in chatify

i even tried to open image on new tab it redirects to this links

"http://localhost:8000/public/attachments/12346d6f-4848-441c-a245-7e1b138ca870.jpg"

but still I get 404 error.

for Image to be displayed on chatify

Comment: Did you run php artisan storage:link ?

Answer (score 0):

In the redirect URL **/image** path is missing that's why you are getting 404 error please edit the filesystem.php file

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('/images'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
```